# Pass dynamic variable in array attribute

Tags: javascript, salesforce-lightning

Wasting again ridiculous time on the following simple question:

How do I pass a dynamic string in an array as a property?
The following does not work:

```
<c:comlib_Quotes arrayReplaceStrings="['{!v.lead.HOM_ContentsAmount__c }']" />
```

The following does work:

```
<c:comlib_Quotes arrayReplaceStrings="['some hard coded value']" />
```

The exception thrown is:

> Cannot mix expression and literal string in attribute value, try
>   rewriting like {!'foo' + v.bar}

Tried every possible combination, can't get good resources online.

Comment: I am not familiar with salesforce-lightning, but if it's anything like other JS framework I would try something like `arrayReplaceStrings="{[!v.lead.HOM_ContentsAmount__c]}"`

Comment: @Morphyish That won't work unfortunately `{! ... }` has special meaning in Salesforce lightning. Your entire syntax would be passed on like a string.

Comment: How about this? `<c:comlib_Quotes arrayReplaceStrings="[v.lead.HOM_ContentsAmount__c]" />` If that `v` is the variable you're getting a string from, maybe that's it?

Comment: My bad I thought it was used as a classic reverse operator. maybe `{!'[\'' + v.lead.HOM_ContentsAmount__c + '\']'}` then ? Should return a string similar to what your have in your static example (if the \ symbol can be used to escape the ')

Comment: @Cerbrus This just prints the entire string as string value instead of parsing it. :-/ v is a lightning thing that refers to the view.

Comment: It was worth a shot :P

Comment: @Morphyish Nope... this prints `[`. Lightning really drives me crazy...

Comment: Do you have any way to store the desired output as a string in a variable beforehand ?

Comment: @Morphyish It is not a bad idea. I could try to send a list of strings and convert it to an array afterwards. Let me check that.

Comment: @Morphyish Fixed it this way. Thanks for the suggestion. Not the cleanest solution but we gotta go with the tools that we have.